# Send a key code to an application without activating it first?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to send the spacebar key to an application without activating it first. The following code almost does what I want but it brings the application to the foreground first.

```
tell application "X"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49
end tell
```

Comment: Um - this may seem obvious, but why not just comment out the `activate` ? Does this mean that the key event then gets sent to the wrong app ?

Comment: I thought telling the process to do so would work: `tell app "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to keystroke "Hello World"`. But I'm not on my computer and thus cannot test it.

Comment: Using either suggestion causes the key to be pressed in the currently active application.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: This is likely to be the sort of task that GUIs were not designed for and therefore may not be easily done. I also hope that there is a way to do this. To help clarify, I'm sure OP means to get similar behavior as scrolling in a background window with the mouse without focusing it, which generally works on Linux WM's and OS X (and not on Windows). But instead of scrolling, to direct keys to those windows.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as off-topic. The asker has demonstrated (at least) a minimal understanding of the topic and posted his code. Although this seems a simple question, I think it should be re-opened.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed it looks fine to me. I've reopened it.

Comment: Not applescript solution but simple `swift` code example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604426/632407

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can send a keystroke to an inactive application.

But you can hide an app immediately after activating it and executing code for it. This does however, cause the app to briefly flash before it hides, unless the app is running in fullscreen.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "X" to activate
    key code 49
    set visible of process "X" to false
end tell
```

Comment: You are wrong, at least if you use all of AppleScript's capacities. Instead of "activate" and "visible false" just let AS . . . . . . . . do shell script "open -g /Path/to/application/X/" . . . . . . . . which opens "X" in background. This is OF COURSE also true if "X" is already open.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a keystroke can basically be seen as using a keyboard, but the only difference is that the keys that need to be pressed are already predefined. The rest of the process revolving around this doesn't change. This means that the application itself still needs to be opened and activated before you can actually send keystrokes to it.

Depending on the application however, it might be possible to use certain Applescript functions in the application's API to send different inputs to the application without having to activate it first. Take the Messages API for instance:

```
tell application "Messages"
      set theBuddy to buddy "someone@mac.com" of service "iMessage"
      send "Hi there" to theBuddy
end tell
```

Comment: You are mistaken in that an app has to be "activated" by AppleScript. It is very well possible to have an app "activated" in the BACKGROUND by the simple command . . . do shell script "open -g /Path/to/application/X/" . . . which even works with apps that are already open in background. Any commands sent to this app are received and executed ALSO in background.

Answer (score 0):

How about deactivating it afterwards?

```
activate application "X"
tell application "System Events" to key code 49
activate me
```

Answer (score 0):

Position is offscreen to prevent it from flashing where the user can see it or reduce its opacity.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a specific command tool that is easy to deal with
https://github.com/socsieng/sendkeys

Answer (score -1):

There are courses of investigation.

1. If the application is one you have developed yourself you have the following options:

   *simply have a public property exposed and set that to the key you want to send it.
   *have your application polling a folder for a file and you send your instructions via that.
2. With a windows API hook of some type you can get control of the application without activating it. I am pretty certain if I put my mind to it I could take control of anything on the computer.

In simple terms think out of the box, it does not necessarily need to be a key press you send, you just want to instruct it to do something. There is loads of options Interface Marshalling, Interops, OLE, DDE, looks like I have turned up on this site just in time!