# How can AppleScript be used to send key codes (or an equivalent) directly to an application?

Tags: macos, automation, keyboard, applescript

For instance, while the following is able to send multiple keys (shift+h) to the application "System Events", the script won't compile when attempting to send those key codes to an application such as Google Chrome. Is there another way?

```
tell application "System Events" (* won't work with "Google Chrome" *)
    key code 58  
    key code 4 
end tell
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Send a key code to an application without activating it first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4996334/253056)

Comment: `key code` belongs exclusively to `System Events`, the codes are sent **always** to the frontmost application.

Comment: Updating to include '(or some key code equivalent)'

Comment: @vadian is absolutely correct, and the two answers below are both wrong, unfortunately.  To send keypress events to a specific application, you need to use the Objective-C bridge and JavaScript for Automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can send key codes via System Events to an application like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        set frontmost to true
        key code 4
        key code 14
        key code 37
        key code 35
    end tell
end tell
```

You can try this by opening Google Chrome first and making sure the focus is on the (empty) URL field and then run the above script - it should type "help" into the URL field.

If you don’t want Chrome to remain in front you can hide it again after sending the key codes.

Comment: The reason I need to send the codes to the application directly is so that the process can happen without having to switch applications. Perhaps there is a way via means of triggering an automation or service task, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: You mean you don't want Google Chrome to be the frontmost app when this happens ?

Comment: _System Events_ **cannot** send key codes to a specific application, only the frontmost application.  As you stated, "[make] sure the focus is on the URL field".  Therefore, `tell process "Google Chrome"` is not necessary at all.  Despite the two upvotes, this answer is, sadly, incorrect.

Comment: The `tell process “Google Chrome”` + `set frontmost to true` is what makes Chrome the frontmost application, so that it can receive the following key codes. You could probably just use `activate` instead, I imagine. But as you say, there doesn’t seem to be any way to send key codes to an application which is not frontmost

Answer (score 0):

***As "commented", key codes & keystrokes can NOT be sent to BG apps by AppleScript!***

It is *ONLY* possible to trigger some other ("visible"!) UI elements while in background.
To this purpose you <strike>must</strike>°° can "select" an application without bringing it to front by:

```
do shell script "open -g /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane/"
```

… which works even if the app is already "open" in background.

°°I was reminded though: AS ***can*** `reveal` Sys.Prefs in background, other apps ***can not.***
A 2nd alternative in AS is `launch` which with *some(!)* apps will work like `"open -g …"`.

As CJK mentions any next command can be sent via AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" ¬
  to click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
```

I use this feature to toggle some Sys-Prefs settings without losing focus. *

**Remember**: *ONLY* commands for "visible elements" (checkboxes, buttons …) will be executed; menu items therefore are excluded (= not visible while in background).

* *["At home" I use these lines in a Karabiner-shortcut where AS need an* `osascript` *wrapping.]*

Comment: Having System Events click a checkbox in System Preferences in the background is not at all relevant to the OP which is wanting to send key codes, and System Events always sends key codes to the frontmost window!

Comment: In addition to what @user3439894 has stated, why also did you supply an answer using shell commands when there was no such context provided by the OP's question ?  You also should format your code blocks correctly, which I've gone ahead and done for you.  See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: **System Events always sends key codes to the frontmost window!**

Comment: I corrected my answer so it is no longer false, but explains what _IS POSSIBLE_ to send to a background application, using shell scripts in AppleScript.

Comment: May I ask why you used the shell scripts here ?  It seems an unexpected choice and I'm wondering if you had a particular reason that I've overlooked ?  Well done for taking on board the comments and editing your answer.

Comment: You may. I use a shell script in the 1st case because it allows the "-g" operator, which invokes the "open" command to work _in background_. . . . . . The 2nd shell script in this context was not necessary: . . . . . The reason I used it at 1st is that I assigned the whole example to a shortcut (via Karabiner Elements) where AppleScripts can not be executed directly.

Comment: You need to tag me in replies if I am to be notified.  You can open _System Preferences_ in the background via AppleScript.  `tell application "System Preferences" to reveal pane "Keyboard"` will do that by default.

Comment: Well, I wasn't notified of your answer ;-) . . . `reveal` does _NOT_ work with "any" application or with Google Chrome, does it? . . . Mine _DOES_ work with these.

Comment: You said "[I was reminded: Sys.Prefs CAN be "reveal"ed by AS in background. OTHER apps can NOT.]" and this is just not totally true! Just use the  `launch` _command_  e.g.  `launch application "TextEdit"`. Note however, this does not keep some apps in the background, therefore the use of `open -g ...` serves a valid purpose.

Comment: @user3439894 Actually "launch" drifted through my head while I brushed my teeth last night. Thanks for clarifying that issue. . . . . . If you don't mind (or vote down) I'll leave my answer to this question; may be of interest to someone looking more generally …