# Send keypress to specific window on Mac

Tags: macos

I'm working on a program that needs to send keystrokes to other (unfocused) windows.

For Windows I use the following native function from WinAPI:

```
SendMessage( HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
```

`hWnd` is the target window handle, `Msg` is set to a key down/up event code and `wParam` is used to specify the key code.

Is there an equivalent to this in a Mac OS API? or any other way to achieve the same effect without having to bring the target window to foreground? I'm looking for solutions that can be implemented with one of the following languages: Java, C++, C, AppleScript.

**Progress update:**

I found the function [CGEventTapCreateForPSN(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454828-cgeventtapcreateforpsn) in the CoreGraphics API and according to the documentation it should do exactly what I want to do. BUT I don't know how to access it from a Java program. As far as I know, the CoreGraphics API is accessible only from Objective-C and Swift, both of which I don't know how to integrate into a Java program. I can execute C and C++ code using JNI, and AppleScript by executing the `osascript` process. I am not very familiar with these 3 languages so I don't know if there is a way to somehow execute Objective-C or Swift code from them (nor from Java), any help with that is greatly appreciated.

I am considering the option of creating a Swift or Objective-C program, compiling it and storing it inside the Java program's .jar file, and then extracting it into a temp folder and executing it when I need to send the keystroke events. I guess it would work, but I would really like it if there was a more elegant solution that doesn't require executing a second program every time I want to send a keystroke.

Comment: Related: [Send a key code to an application without activating it first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996334/send-a-key-code-to-an-application-without-activating-it-first)

Comment: @Willeke I saw this one, doesn't solve my problem though, that question was specifically about AppleScript which seems to not be capable of sending keys to a visible not focused application.

Comment: You can send a keystroke to another process, but not necessarily to a specific window, using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and `CGEventPostToPid`.

Comment: @JWWalker I need it to be to a specific unfocused window, so these won't do it, and as I mentioned in the progress update in my question: this API is not accessible from a Java program, not even with JNI.

Comment: I don't see how `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` would solve the problem of directing an event to a specific window.  That said, (1) CoreGraphics is a C API (I don't know if you can tell that from the docs, but look at the header CGEvent.h), and (2) you'd be more likely to use `CGEventTapCreateForPid` since a PSN is an obsolete data structure that you can't really get any more.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you posted an example of how to use `CGEventTapCreateForPid`, or gave a link to a documentation (since I can't find any documentation on it myself)

Comment: There's no documentation for `CGEventTapCreateForPid`, but the parameters are the same as for `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` except that it takes a process ID instead of a process serial number.  Normally I would get a pid using `NSRunningApplication`, but if you can't use Cocoa, it's probably possible to do it using some Unix APIs.

Comment: This sounds like an interprocess communication.  There are many options to choose from. Why keystroke?

Comment: @psksvp because I was working on a program that sends commands to a Flash game (I didn't make the game) to perform a routine task while I'm doing something else on the computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demo in `swift`, using

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
```

simple example code `sendspace.swift`

```
import Foundation

let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)
    
let kspd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: true)   // space-down
let kspu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: false)  // space-up

let pids = [ 24834, 24894, 24915 ]; // real PID-s from command 'ps -ax' - e.g. for example 3 different processes
    
for i in 0 ..< pids.count {
    print("sending to pid: ", pids[i]);
    kspd?.postToPid( pid_t(pids[i]) ); // convert int to pid_t
    kspu?.postToPid( pid_t(pids[i]) );
}
```

After running the code: `swift sendspace.swift` (from the Terminal) all 3 processes with defined PIDs will get the <kbd>space</kbd> keypress, while the Terminal is still the foreground app.

Comment: Code used wrong imports:


import Foundation
import Quartz

let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)

let kspd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: true)   // space-down
let kspu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: false)  // space-up

let pids = [ 24834, 24894, 24915 ] // real PID-s from command 'ps -ax' - e.g., for example, 3 different processes

for pid in pids {
    print("sending to pid: ", pid)
    kspd?.postToPid( pid_t(pid) ) // convert int to pid_t
    kspu?.postToPid( pid_t(pid) )
}